# Fancytree passing parameters when loading nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

How can I pass parameter to .NET web method with fancytree

```
Public Shared Function ReadNodes(parentId As String) As String
```

I am trying to send it like this, but it always gets sent as a querystring parameter.

```
$("#tree").fancytree( {
    source: {
        url: "Default.aspx/ReadNodes",
        data: {parentId: "-1"},
        cache: false
    }
} )
```

Can I somehow pass the value to a method as a parameter?

This doesnt work, I keep getting a loading wheel and then a failure. No javascript errors in console.

I have also tried the server method without a parameter, and I get the same behavior. So perhaps I am doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your web method must return an array like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static IEnumerable ReadNodes(int parentId)
{
    return new[] { 
       new { title = string.Format("1. Child of '{0}'", parentId) },
       new { title = string.Format("2. Child of '{0}'", parentId) }
       // ...
    };
}
```

And then you call the web method like this

```
$('#tree').fancytree({
    source: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Default.aspx/ReadNodes',
        data: '{ parentId: -1 }',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        dataType: 'json'
    }
});
```